# IdentityServer4 oidc-client error - authority mismatch on settings vs. signin state

Tags: identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I have an IdentityServer4 and C# .NET Core web application behind an NGINX reverse proxy:

https://id.local.domain -> http://id-local

https://web.local.domain -> http://web-local

I can get to and enter my credentials on the ID4 login page, but after being redirected back to my /account/callback page from ID4, the following JavaScript error appears:

Error: authority mismatch on settings vs. signin state

Is this a problem with my oidc call, the NGINX + ID4 setup, or something else? I have tried using:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
options.PublicOrigin = "https://id.local.domain";
…
```

Is that the correct URL to enter? Do I need to use options.IssuerUri instead of/as well?

Comment: configs like redirect urls and clientId must be the same between your javascript client and your identity server, check that the config is the same and that you allowed your client root url in cors

Comment: Looks like that was the issue across a couple of places. I went through and checked that everything matched, as well as the CORS configuration for all services. Some additional items I changed were ensuring the CORS url casing was the same, whitespace removed etc. That seems to have done the trick - thanks!!! If you want to post your post as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the identity server will not accept or allow clients only if the config sent from the clients  match with its config

- same Redirect Urls
- same ClientID
- same ClientRoot (client base url have to be allowed in cors)